# Нумерованый список html

Tags: html, visual-studio

need your help with my homework.
[image: how to make this]

[image: like this]

[image: my code]

Comment: [Доки.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) и [пример](https://webref.ru/recipe/2309) *(используется счётчик, для более кастомизируемого списка)*. Там *(на сайта Mozilla)* описаны вообще все возможные методы.

Comment: это русская версия srackoverflow вопросы должны быть заданы на русском, пример кода должен быть добавлен кодом а не скрином https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  /* Квадратные маркеры */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <ol type="i">
    <li> граматика</li>
    <li> орфология</li>
  </ol>
  <ul>
    <li>история украины</li>
  </ul>
  <ol type="i">
    <li value="3"> истрия руси</li>
    <li> казацтва</li>
  </ol>
</ul>
```